# Find a column value which is repeated against another column in R

Tags: r, select, dataframe

I have a sales dataframe where I have dates in 1 column which is spread over at-least 3 years, CustomerId, transaction and transaction amount.

```
       Date   Cust.ID     Transact.Amt
12-Aug-2013         1              64
12-Aug-2014         1             154
15-Dec-2013         2              85
17-Dec-2013         1             135
```

I am trying to retrieve `Cust.ID` who have purchased over 2 years , which in this case will be 1 ?

I tried using Duplicated function, but it removed the original values.

I am really starting out in R, would appreciate if someone shares their approach.

Comment: ohh , it stands for Employee which is captured in Cust.ID here, let me edit it

Comment: So if customer purchased 2013 and 2015, would they be included?

Comment: How about customer purchased 2013December and 2014January? `who have purchased over 2 years` - is not very clear.

Comment: @zx8754 ,yes they would also be included,basically everyone who has more than 1 transaction specially in different years

Comment: @zx8754 , yes for Dec 2013 and Jan 2014 also , I would want to retrieve that person

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `table` to find out how many transactions each customer has made for each year and check how many years each customer actually made transactions and specify threshold you would like to check for each customer:

```
library(lubridate)
tab <- table(df$Cust.ID, year(dmy(df$Date)))
tab
#   2013 2014
# 1    2    1
# 2    1    0

rowSums(tab != 0) >= 2
#    1     2 
# TRUE FALSE
```

Another `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df %>% 
      group_by(Cust.ID) %>% 
      summarise(n_years = n_distinct(year(dmy(Date)))) %>% 
      filter(n_years >= 2)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  Cust.ID n_years
#    <chr>   <int>
#1       1       2
```

*Update* for original data frame subsetting:

```
df %>% 
      group_by(Cust.ID) %>% 
      filter(n_distinct(year(dmy(Date))) >= 2)

#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: Cust.ID [1]

#          Date Cust.ID Transact.Amt
#         <chr>   <chr>        <chr>
# 1 12-Aug-2013       1           64
# 2 12-Aug-2014       1          154
# 3 17-Dec-2013       1          135
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I apply rowSums,the problem is that if a Customer has transacted in a year 2013 three times and one time in 2014 , then the sum will be 4, but is there a way I can find if the customer has changed year?

Comment: Did you check tab != 0? You should check that and then row sum.

Comment: Yes you are right, I get TRUE FALSE for people spread across 2 years, could you please explain what does tab !=0 mean ? Also when I pass the rowSums(tab != 0) >= 2 to the dataframe to select the records which are spread across different years, I retrieve data which are spread across in a single year as well, any thoughts ?

Comment: `tab != 0` checks whether a customer has made transaction with a year so it will count only once even if the customer made several transactions in a year. Updated the answer for getting records from original data frame, change the summarize to mutate should work.

Comment: Or if you want to work with the first option. Try this, `df[df$Cust.ID %in% names(which(rowSums(tab != 0) >= 2)), ]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Cust.ID', we convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, extract the 'Year' and `if` the length of `unique` elements are greater than 1, we get the Subset of Data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(format(as.Date(Date, "%d-%b-%Y"), "%Y"))>1) .SD, by = Cust.ID]
#   Cust.ID        Date Transact.Amt
#1:       1 12-Aug-2013           64
#2:       1 12-Aug-2014          154
#3:       1 17-Dec-2013          135
```